Maven build fails in Command line ; successful from eclipse
1.When I am trying to run jar file which is created by maven project through command line it is show error
2.After adding Guava version of 25.0-jre error occur
3.I am using selenium version 3.141.59 and Java version 17.0
4.I am using command to run jar file is it correct
java -jar
5.Tried Guava version 25.0-jre
6.facing error Caused by:  because "this.driver" is null
Caused by: NoSuchMethodError

Please show the pom file... which Maven version do you use ? Also please to run on plain command not from inside your IDE etc...

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.

Probably you just tried to run a JAR that is not an executable JAR (fat JAR). You can run it from the IDE, but not from the command line. There you need Maven shade plugin or Maven assembly plugin.
